# ¿Cómo hacer para que salgan las comparaciones de Kruskall Wallis en el gráfico?

Tags: r, ggplot

Soy muy nueva en R y todavía no estoy familiarizada con el código. Estoy intentando crear un bucle para generar unos gráficos con las comparaciones en el gráfico de todas las variables en una base de datos con el test Kruskall Wallis. He generado este código que adjunto a continuación, y se genera el gráfico pero no salen las comparaciones. ¿Alguna idea?

```
# Librerias 
library(readr)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

 # Cargar datos
Datos <- read_xls("C:/Users/Desktop/R/Bases/3 grups.xls")

Datos[,3:38] <- lapply(Datos[3:38], as.numeric)

Datos <- as.data.frame(Datos)

Datos$Grup <- as.factor(Datos$Grup)

Datos$Grup <- factor(Datos$Grup, levels = c("CT", "NASH", "CH"))

my_comparison <- list( c("CT", "NASH"), c("CT", "CH"), c("NASH", "CH"))


# Abrir dispositivo grafico fuera del bucle
png("plots.png", res = 300, height = 2000, width = 4000)

variables <- names(Dades_Rosa)

ruta_carpeta <- "C:/Users/Desktop/R/Bases/prova"

# Crear el gráfico y realizar el test de Kruskal-Wallis para cada variable
for (variable_actual in variables) {
  # Título personalizado para cada gráfico
  titol_grafic <- paste("", variable_actual)

  # Crear el gráfico
  grafic <- ggplot(Datos, aes(x = Grup, y = .data[[variable_actual]], color = Grup)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    labs(x = "", y = "%") +
    stat_summary(fun = median, geom = "point", size = 2, color = "red") +
    geom_dotplot(binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center', dotsize = 1) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("CT" = "#FF8C00", "NASH" = "#1E90FF", "CH" = "#7FFF00")) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 15, hjust = 1, vjust = 1, size = 20),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20),
          legend.key.size = unit(1, 'cm'),
          legend.title = element_text(size = 20),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 20),
          plot.title = element_text(size = 35, hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(b = 75))) +
    stat_compare_means(method = "kruskal.test", comparisons = my_comparison) +  # Realiza el test de Kruskal-Wallis
    guides(color = "none") +
    ggtitle(titol_grafic)

  # Guardar el gráfico
  nom_fitxer <- file.path(ruta_carpeta, paste0("", gsub(" ", " ", variable_actual), ".png"))
  ggsave(nom_fitxer, plot = grafic, device = "png", width = 10, height = 6)
}
dev.off()
```